# List index out of range python in a for loop

Tags: python, arrays, json, loops

I am trying to split the lines in a text document into an array, and append attributes to each of the values in the array before converting them to json to be displayed in a text file.

However, no matter how I tweak my codes, I still encounter the error "
**IndexError: list index out of rang**e" for the fields1[1] line.

```
    with open(fileName,'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        if line.startswith('-') and 'section1' in line:
            for li in file:
                fields1 = li.split(',')
                testarr.append({
                "section1a": fields1[0],
                "section1b": fields1[1],
                "section1c": fields1[2]
                })      
                with open(test_dir,'a+') as test_file:
                    json.dump(testarr, test_file)
```

Any idea where the problem lies in?

Comment: Can you provide the input file contents here?

Comment: 2011-12-05 11:30:00,54321, 12345 
the above line is a sample of the input. there are 3 columns so technically fields[2] should still work @SainathBatthala

Comment: Also, I added a print statement for all 3 columns, it is able to print all 3 fields but i dont know why i am not able to append it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some strange indenting and without the contents I'm not sure where your error would be, but this should help you find it:

```
testarr = []
with open(fileName,'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        if line.startswith('-') and 'section1' in line:
            fields1 = li.split(',')
            if len(fields1) >= 3:
                testarr.append(
                    {
                    "section1a": fields1[0],
                    "section1b": fields1[1],
                    "section1c": fields1[2]
                    }
                )
            else:
                print("This line has an error in it: {}".format(line))

with open(test_dir,'a+') as test_file:
    json.dump(testarr, test_file)
```

Answer (score 2):

When you did `li.split(',')`, it did not split into 3 parts. May be it did not have enough `,` to split. For example .. `li = 'asdf,ffd'` This will give error on fields1[2] because it will split into 2 parts only `['asdf', 'ffd']`.